# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'telegram.utils'

Tags: python, telegram

I have installed python-telegram-bot like:

`pip install python-telegram-bot`

When I'm try to do this:

```
from telegram.ext import Updater, CommandHandler, MessageHandler, filters
from telegram.utils.helpers import escape_markdown
```

I get this error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'telegram.utils'
```

Comment: Post the exact output of the `pip` command and the error message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [telegram sourcecode](https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot/blob/master/telegram/helpers.py#L44):

The function `escape_markdown` is located in `telegram/helpers.py`, so the correct import should be next:

```
root@shdebian1:~# python3
Python 3.9.2 (default, Feb 28 2021, 17:03:44)
[GCC 10.2.1 20210110] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from telegram.helpers import escape_markdown
```